# How to display Date in popup Modal in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to display data in the `popup`, I have a list on products but when a user clicks on the `product id` then it should be open in `popup` according to that product `id`.

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def myview(request):
   datas=TestForm.objects.all
   template_name='test.html'
   context={'datas':datas}
   return render(request, template_name, context)

def myview(request, id):
   display=TestForm.objects.get(pk=id)
   template_name='test.html'
   context={'display':display}
   return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my `test.html` file...

```
 {% for a in datas %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
  target="#exampleModal">
  {{a.product_id}}
   </button>
  {% endfor %}

  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <tr>
     <td>{{datas.name}}</td>
     <td>{{datas.price}}</td>
     <td>{{datas.category}}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, it's displaying the only popup fields on click all products id's, Please let me know how it can display product data according to click product id.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by making the modal `id` attribute unique with the `pk` value.

```
{% for a in datas %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
  target="#exampleModal{{a.pk}}">
  {{a.product_id}}
   </button>
  {% endfor %}
```

Now in  the modal

```
 {% for a in datas %}
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{a.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
.......
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How it can be possible without for loop in modal...if a user clicks on `product_id` then it should be open in a popup without using for loop...

Comment: then you need some js to handle this.

Comment: I am trying to add JS but it's not working, could you please write the JS code

Comment: I want to do it using jquery...because in my next form I will update data using popup form

Comment: Hi Arjun, Could you please solve this issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020362/how-to-display-ajax-response-data-in-popup